# '+' packaging or modular programming in matlab: analog of python's import?

Tags: matlab, namespaces, packaging

I come with the background in languages like Java or Python where modular programming is enabled by packaging system and import directive (aka namespace aliasing). Historically MATLAB's approach to resolve problems like naming conflicts boils down to setting/playing with MATLABPATH, renaming/extending identifiers with prefixes, etc. So far I have been successfully playing with native MATLAB packaging by prepending plus sign "+" before the folder name (MATLAB notation for package also see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html)). Obviously  they are very long to type ;-) Basically I am back to the similar problem as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076365/what-is-the-scope-of-matlabs-import-function) with no solution. So let me paraphrased for my particular angle:

Assume I have folder **+mypackage** defined containing file **myfun.m** with the function code of the same name.

How to achieve aliasing for MATLAB function inside the user (non-java) package as illustrated by the following python code:

```
from mypackage import myfun
```

?

[**EDIT**] <strike>Please note that AFAIK import keyword works only for [java classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) (with jvm attached to MATLAB process).</strike>  No, import is working perfectly fine for both functions and aliases for objects and function of both Java and MATLAB origin.

Possibly related but not the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315047/using-matlab-to-import-another-m-file).

[**EDIT2**]

python's

```
from mypackage import myfun as anotherfun
```

is equivalent to MATLAB's

```
anotherfun = @mypackage.myfun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't

```
import mypackage.myfun
```

work?

[link to documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html)

Comment: It does. Checking it on the newest version. In addition what is missing is from mypackage import myfun as anotherfun. But that is equivalent to anotherfun = @mypackage.myfun I will shortly update the question.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich: Glad it works. I suggest creating a script for recurring import/rename tasks.